# Plugin disappears on frontend after theme changing

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am developing a plugin for Woocommerce. I thought it would be nice if the plugin looked nice in different themes. So I downloaded a theme and installed and activated it.

So I checked the plugin on the product page. But it wasn't there!

I changed back to some other theme and it showed up again!

So my question is, is this my fault for developing a not-so dynamic plugin?
Or is this the fault of the theme creator?
And what are the possible explanations/solutions for those kind of problems?

Example:

Twenty fifteen:

[image: Working]

Other theme:

[image]

The elements of my plugin are not there as far as I've seen.

**Edit**

I am using the woocommerce_after_main_content hook.

Which I do like this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'ws_action_woocommerce_after_main_content', 10);
```

This calls my function which runs a shortcode.

Like this:

```
function ws_action_woocommerce_after_main_content() {

  do_shortcode('[ws_frame]');

}
```

This shortcode ofcourse has the function with `<h1>Hello, I'm here!</h1>`

**Summary of how my plugin works**

My plugin is a designer plugin for shirts (May aswell be for other products).

The plugin has an options page in the backend.

My plugin only gets loaded if Woocommerce is active. Also, the plugin only gets shown on the product page IF the product is in the specified category.

Using shortcodes, the front end layout is generated in a function, where some enqueued scripts and css is present. The function also has some HTML.

As mentioned above, I am using `woocommerce_before_main_content` hook.
 This calls a function which has the `do_shortcode('[ws_frame]')` in it.
 This shortcode as the enqueued scripts, css and has some HTML.
 Yet, I do have `ob_flush();` before the `do_shortcode('[ws_frame]')`.
 So this might be something?
Also, there isn't much more going on for the front end of this plugin. This is what have done to make it appear on the product page. The options page in the admin panel still works.

The question still remains, is it me, who needs to fix this, or is this something the theme creator is responsible for?
And how can I fix this myself? How can I make sure all of the hooks I'm using are still available in that theme?
 Even if it is the theme's creators fault, I would like to know how I can fix this myself.

Comment: Please add some more information like which action causes the plugin data to display in the theme (in which it displays). Are you adding your plugin data to any of the woocommerce's action (via `add_action`).

Comment: what elements are we talking about here? and how did you write your plugin? using hooks or whatever?

Comment: Thank you, updated my question.

Comment: @zipkundan, If you have any idea how I can place my plugin more freely on the product page, I'd love to hear! As I can only place my plugin on two different locations. Outside the product main content div and inside the product main content div at the very end.

Comment: Well, can explain what your plugin actually does or what is your intention for creating this plugin? I am asking this because may be based on that, your plugin might be hooked with some other action instead of the action you have used. Some themes may remove this action altogether and add their their own wrapper.

Comment: @zipkundan, I will try to explain it in my question. As I have no idea how to  explain it in a few sentences. I will give you a sign when I updated my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be wrong but I guess in your case the theme for which your plugin is not displayed has the particular action removed. (you may check that in the respective theme's functions file.) Well, it is better idea to hook your plugin (functionality related into some action hook which is related to functionality or which renders some funcitonality (rather than being an UI related action).

Like, the action you have used to hook your plugin `woocommerce_after_main_content` along with another action, only outputs an html element wrapper. (which some themes might remove and use their custom html wrapper.

In your case since your plugin is related to / displayed on single product page, I would recommend to use relevant action to hook your plugin. e.g. `woocommerce_after_single_product_summary` or `woocommerce_after_single_product`, which are generally not removed by woocommerce compatible themes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `woocommerce_after_single_product` Worked instantly. Thank you very much! Also, do you have any idea how I can move my plugin layout? Like before product description? Thanks again!

Comment: I would recommend you to analyse the woo's default template file for single product `content-single-product.php`. (located /plugins/woocommerce/templates/content-single-product.php) There you will find various action (hooks) placed hierarchically. Some of them also contribute to the page layout / frontend in conjunction with css. This way you will be able to analyze the suitable position for your plugin and also learn more about woocommerce structure and actions. For perticularly what you asked, check the action `woocommerce_single_product_summary`

Comment: Some urls to get you started with 
https://docs.woothemes.com/document/introduction-to-hooks-actions-and-filters/

https://www.skyverge.com/blog/hook-into-woocommerce-actions/

Comment: Awesome, I'll be at it! Thanks!